# What is the tfidf matrix giving ideally

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tf-idf

when i ran the tfidf for a set of documents it returned me a tfidf matrix which looked like this.

```
(1, 12) 0.656240233446
  (1, 11)   0.754552023393
  (2, 6)    1.0
  (3, 13)   1.0
  (4, 2)    1.0
  (7, 9)    1.0
  (9, 4)    0.742540927053
  (9, 5)    0.66980069547
  (11, 19)  0.735138466738
  (11, 7)   0.677916982176
  (12, 18)  1.0
  (13, 14)  0.697455191865
  (13, 11)  0.716628394177
  (14, 5)   1.0
  (15, 8)   1.0
  (16, 17)  1.0
  (18, 1)   1.0
  (19, 17)  1.0
  (22, 13)  1.0
  (23, 3)   1.0
  (25, 6)   1.0
  (26, 19)  0.476648253537
  (26, 7)   0.879094103268
  (28, 10)  0.532672175403
  (28, 7)   0.523456282204
```

I want to know what is this, I am not able to understand how this is provided.
when i was in debug mode I got to know about indices, indptr and data... this things are some where co-relating with the data given. what are these? 
there are lots of confusion in the numbers, I dont see 0th, 5th, 6th document if I say the first element in the parenthesis is the documents based on my prediction. 
Kindly help me figure out how it is working here. However I know the general working of tfidf from wiki, taking the log on inverse documents and other stuff. I just want to know what are these 3 different kind of numbers here, what are the refering it to?

The source code is :

```
#This contains the list of file names 
_filenames =[]
#This conatains the list if contents/text in the file
_contents = []
#This is a dict of filename:content
_file_contents = {}
class KmeansClustering():   
   def kmeansClusters(self):
        global _report
            self.num_clusters = 5
            km = KMeans(n_clusters=self.num_clusters)
            vocab_frame = TokenizingAndPanda().createPandaVocabFrame()
            self.tfidf_matrix, self.terms, self.dist = TfidfProcessing().getTfidFPropertyData()
            km.fit(self.tfidf_matrix)
            self.clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
            joblib.dump(km, 'doc_cluster2.pkl')
            km = joblib.load('doc_cluster2.pkl')

class TokenizingAndPanda():

    def tokenize_only(self,text):
        '''
        This function tokenizes the text
        :param text: Give the text that you want to tokenize
        :return: it gives the filter tokes
        '''
        # first tokenize by sentence, then by word to ensure that punctuation is caught as it's own token
        tokens = [word.lower() for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
        filtered_tokens = []
        # filter out any tokens not containing letters (e.g., numeric tokens, raw punctuation)
        for token in tokens:
            if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', token):
                filtered_tokens.append(token)
        return filtered_tokens

    def tokenize_and_stem(self,text):
        # first tokenize by sentence, then by word to ensure that punctuation is caught as it's own token
        tokens = [word.lower() for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
        filtered_tokens = []
        # filter out any tokens not containing letters (e.g., numeric tokens, raw punctuation)
        for token in tokens:
            if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', token):
                filtered_tokens.append(token)
        stems = [_stemmer.stem(t) for t in filtered_tokens]
        return stems

    def getFilnames(self):
        '''

        :return:
        '''
        global _path
        global _filenames
        path = _path
        _filenames = FileAccess().read_all_file_names(path)


    def getContentsForFilenames(self):
        global _contents
        global _file_contents
        for filename in _filenames:
            content = FileAccess().read_the_contents_from_files(_path, filename)
            _contents.append(content)
            _file_contents[filename] = content

    def createPandaVocabFrame(self):
        global _totalvocab_stemmed
        global _totalvocab_tokenized
        #Enable this if you want to load the filenames and contents from a file structure.
        # self.getFilnames()
        # self.getContentsForFilenames()

        # for name, i in _file_contents.items():
        #     print(name)
        #     print(i)
        for i in _contents:
            allwords_stemmed = self.tokenize_and_stem(i)
            _totalvocab_stemmed.extend(allwords_stemmed)

            allwords_tokenized = self.tokenize_only(i)
            _totalvocab_tokenized.extend(allwords_tokenized)
        vocab_frame = pd.DataFrame({'words': _totalvocab_tokenized}, index=_totalvocab_stemmed)
        print(vocab_frame)
        return vocab_frame


class TfidfProcessing():

    def getTfidFPropertyData(self):
        tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.4, max_features=200000,
                                           min_df=0.02, stop_words='english',
                                           use_idf=True, tokenizer=TokenizingAndPanda().tokenize_and_stem, ngram_range=(1, 1))
        # print(_contents)
        tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(_contents)
        terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
        dist = 1 - cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix)

        return tfidf_matrix, terms, dist
```

Comment: Are you talking about the [scikit-learn tf-idf](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) ?
Can you put a part of your code and extracts from the documents you want to extract info from ?

Comment: ya its scikit-learn tf-idf is what was talking, well a part of my code is posted above, hope u can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of tfidf applied to data is usually a 2D matrix A, where A_ij is the normalized j'th term (word) frequency in i'th document. What you see in your output is **sparse** representation of this matrix, in other words - only elements which are non-zero are printed out, so:

```
(1, 12) 0.656240233446
```

means that 12th word (according to some vocabulary that has been built by sklearn) has a normalized frequency 0.656240233446 in the first document. The "missing" bits are zero, meaning that for example 3rd word cannot be find in 1st document (since there is no `(1,3)`) and so on.

The fact that some documents are missing is a result of your particular code/data (which you did not include), maybe you set the vocabulary by hand? Or maximum number of features considered? There are many parameters in TfidfVectorizer that can cause that, but without your exact code (and some exemplary data) nothing else can be said. For example setting `min_df` can cause that (as it drops very rare words) similarly `max_features` (the same effect)

Comment: Hi @lejlot thanks for the explanation, I have also posted part of my source code above. hope u can help me guide with respect to min_df , max_df, max_features... How it works, like how can we get better accuracy in the clustering and why some documents are missing.

Comment: Basically drop max_df, min_df and max_features and you should get all the documents. There is no "magical" way of setting this things, you can only follow (somehow guided) trial and error, but start without setting them at all.

Comment: Ya sure I will try that way and let you know how it goes... Thank you

Comment: Hi @lejlot can I know what this min_df and max_df  exactly do? I refered the documentation I was not able to understand that, can u simplify and let me why do we use it, whats the purpose of that...

Comment: df is "document frequency", so for each word in how many distinct documents it can be found. By setting min and max you say that you **only** want words that occur in between min_df and max_df of your documents, so this is an extremely arbitrary thing, and should rather be avoided.